# need to add /public/ to the packages assets root path of laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

My Laravel installation is in a subfolder/subapp. I then installed Backpack 4.1. Url of backpack login is something like http://example.test/laravel/admin/login.

My Laravel is running fine as a second app in the subfolder (I used nginx to manage the main app and the laravel app as second app in sub-folder).

But the backpack page is not loading the CSS and JS files as /public/ of laravel is missing in the path.

I tried to add ASSET_URL=public in .env of laravel. But did not work.

Need help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Below is the block I put in nginx. (fradmin / "nested") has Laravel. then backpack is in Laravel

 location /fradmin {
        alias /mnt/c/Projects/fradmin/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @nested {
        rewrite /fradmin/(.*)$ /fradmin/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

Comment: Please add your code to the question body and format it properly.

Comment: Also, can you more clearly explain the actual problem? The `/public` should not be in _any_ of your laravel urls, thats not how the routing works.